# Updating JQueryUI .button() when called again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a post which returns a new page.  That page has a `<a> link </a>` which upon the pages return I call `$( "a" ).button();`.  I have already called this on the original page so all of my buttons are already formatted as a JQueryUI Button.  However, the new button isn't formatted until I make another post.  Is there a way

```
$(".mapRelation")
        .click(function( event ) {
        var closestRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        var nextRow = closestRow.next("tr");
        $(this).css("display", "none");
        if(nextRow.attr("id") != "map"){
            $.ajax({
                url: "AddTask.aspx/insertMappingRow",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (res) { 
                    closestRow.after(res.d);
                     },
                error: function (res) { debugger; alert("error"); }
                });
                $("#effect").height("+=25");
                $("#toggler").height("+=25");
        }
        $(".submitMapping").button();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this entire question up and then my colleague answered it for me so maybe it'll help someone else...

The `$(".submitMapping").button();` needs to be placed in the success portion of the AJAX call.  Since AJAX is asynchronous, the `.button()` is happening before your new button is on the page.  If you place `$(".submitMapping").button();` after the `closestRow.after(res.d);` it will call it when it's been placed on the page.